# Creating android layout by xml without android studio layout editor

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, ide, xml-editor

Is any editor to create android layout except android studio or others Android IDE layout editor?
I have 2GB of RAM and android studio or others IDE make crashes a lot. I need to build XML layout for android application , if you know any IDE or XML editor which can be used for android layout (such activity layout or drawable or...) or any suggestion please tell me.

Comment: If you are sure about the xml attributes and tags, you can write the xml in any editor like notepad++ or notepad. There is nothing special about the layout editor, it is just a fancy WYSIWYG representation of the underlying XML markup that makes the layout.

Comment: @mohammadreza khorasani This site should be used for more explicit programming questions (that is, about actual code).

Comment: I would suggest you to use Linux if you have limited RAM.